# Is there stable event ordering in cytoscape.js on same/different event types on one element?

Tags: javascript, events, cytoscape.js

I have a cytoscape graph which has many different events associated with the nodes and edges.

I can see the behavior that if i have some code like:

```
cy.on('click', 'node:parent', function (e) {
        cy.expandCollapse('get').collapse(e.target);
});

cy.on('click', 'node,edge', function (event) {
        console.log("Click on node");
});
```

The node will always complete its collapse before the second event on the node is fired. Is this stable behavior that i can reply upon in terms of event ordering?

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on any ordering of events, apart from what's specified in the documentation.  The only events for which you can expect an ordering are ones that are part of a well defined gesture -- like click is made of mousedown-mouseup.

Comment: Okay. I understand.